# after training accuracy reach 100% it decrease suddenly and return to 100% later. it occurs regularly

Tags: tensorflow

I use my own simulation of the images as a dataset, `0-9, A-Z`, `nac` :

- a total of 37 categories,
- there are fifteen kinds of fonts,
- each font 1000 words per character,
- a total of 509000 pictures (lack of some characters in some fonts) ,
- Of which 70% as training set, 30% as testing set.

The size of the figure is 28x28 grayscale, black background and white word.

With tensorflow mnist that handwritten recognition of the demo network (2 layers conv). Use the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to count loss.

As shown in the figure, respectively, 10000 and 20000 iterations of the results,  why is there such a strange situation? accuracy suddenly fall (regularly)

**iteration 10000**

[image: iteration 10000]

**iteration 20000**

[image: iteration 20000]

Comment: Have you randomised the order of the data? If you're using batch training then it could be that the model only learns (for example) the A-Z and not the numbers. Each time you cycle through the numbers it performs badly but never has a chance to really learn then since a few batches later it's back on letters.

Comment: Thank you. It maybe a reason. I will have a try to do some modification.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to my question:

[Loss increases after restoring checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544793/loss-increases-after-restoring-checkpoint)

Take a look at this [Tensorboard chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chVIP.png)

On my side, every time the model is restored from a checkpoint, I have a drop in performance.